# #php -> SAVE SQL- query result in array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to store my query result in an array, so that I can convert this to Json.
At the moment my result is stored in q. How can I get the result to an array`?

```
$sqlQuery ="SELECT * FROM data2";
$q = $pdo->query($sqlQuery);
```

Comment: You should google for the `fetch()` method

Comment: I've removed the `json` tag since it doesn't really have anything to do with the question on `how can I get the result to an array` and added the `pdo` tag instead.

Comment: $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: With the ->fetch() I can save the data. Now I want to see If all row values are included. How can I cycle trugh the array, if the array is an associative one?

Comment: Are you talking of one row or of several rows? from your query you should get multiple rows

Comment: Either way, use foreach to iterate any arrays